# How and why are Google signing in to my outlook.com account?

Tags: google, outlook.com

I have an outlook.com e-mail account, and when signing in on account.live.com and browsing the security page, viewing recent sign-ins, I see many sign-ins and "unusual activity" originating from the United States (I am far away from the U.S.), from an IP belonging to Google.

What's happening here?

[image: Google signing in to outlook.com account]

Answer (score 2):

This often happens when a Gmail account is set up to "gather" or collect email from Outlook.com via POP or IMAP.

It's a quite handy feature as Gmail allows you to pull those messages and have a single unified "one true in-box" for all your email accounts. Coupled with the option of configuring "sending mail as another account" with true SMTP authentication and relaying, Gmail is able to act as a desktop email client as far as Outlook.com is concerned.

My guess is at some point you did configure at least the mail fetching part on a Gmail  account. If you don't own a Google account, disable POP and IMAP access, and you're done.

If you do own a Gmail account, check the settings under "account preferences" where you can stop that mail fetching without disabling POP or IMAP on Outlook.com.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it has to be something else, because this e-mail account has only ever been used with the built-in e-mail application in Windows 10, and is not entered anywhere else.